# Not right data is being selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m having problem making a little emoticons system for my chat. I´m working with the data attribute of HTML. So that their is a different data for every emoticon.

So this is the HTML part

```
<div class="emoticons">
    <a href="#" data-emot=":)" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-1.png" alt=":)" title=":)"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot=";)" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-2.png" alt=";)" title=";)"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot=":(" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-3.png" alt=":(" title=":("></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot=":D" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-4.png" alt=":D" title=":D"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot=":P" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-5.png" alt=":P" title=":P"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot="=)" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-6.png" alt="=)" title="=)"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot=":|" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-7.png" alt=":|" title=":|"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot="=|" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-8.png" alt="=|" title="=|"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot=">:|" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-9.png" alt=">:|" title=">:|"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot=">:D" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-10.png" alt=">:D" title=">:D"></a>

    <a href="#" data-emot="o_O" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-11.png" alt="o_O" title="o_O"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot="=O" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-12.png" alt="=O" title="=O"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot="<3" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-13.png" alt="<3" title="<3"><!--3--></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot=":S" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-14.png" alt=":S" title=":S"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot=":*" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-15.png" alt=":*" title=":*"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot=":$" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-16.png" alt=":$" title=":$"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot="=B" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-17.png" alt="=B" title="=B"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot=":-D" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-18.png" alt=":-D" title=":-D"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot=";-D" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-19.png" alt=";-D" title=";-D"></a>
    <a href="#" data-emot="*-D" class="emoticon"><img src="emots/emot-20.png" alt="*-D" title="*-D"></a>
</div>
```

This is my JS

```
/* Emoticons part */
$('a[href]').click(function(){
    var emot = $('.emoticon').attr('data-emot');
    $('#inputvalue').val($('#inputvalue').val() + emot);    
});
```

So the problem is that when I press on an emoticon, it needs to give me **:-) or ;-)/(y)**. Now it keeps giving me this **:)**. So it keeps giving me the first one of that list, can somebody help me?

Thank you very much in advance! English isn't also my mother languages, my apologize for any bad grammar of spell mistakes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead of ".emoticon", as you want emotion of that link not others with class "emoticon"

```
       $('a[href]').click(function(){

            var emot = $(this).attr('data-emot');

                $('#inputvalue').val($('#inputvalue').val() + emot);    
          });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I will accept your answer in 11 minutes due the time here on SO.

Comment: No problem, great to hear :)

Comment: you can also use `$(this).data('emot')`

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
var emot = $('.emoticon').attr('data-emot');
```

to this:

```
var emot = $(this).attr('data-emot');
```